# How to show vertical scrollbar only for iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, scroll

The following html code deosn't show the vertical scrollabr . why ?

```
 <style>
        #mapIframe{
            min-height:300px;
            overflow:auto !important;
            direction:rtl  !important;
            overflow-x:hidden   !important;
            overflow-y:scroll   !important;
            height:100%; //optional, but it can't hurt.
        }
    </style>




<iframe id="mapIframe" src="aurl" width="300" height="800" frameBorder="0">Browser not compatible.</iframe>
```

Comment: `scrolling="no"` What would it mean...?

Comment: Your code works perfect to me. my code ---- <iframe src="http://domain.tld/shop/" frameborder="0" style="overflow-y:scroll !important;overflow-x:hidden !important; overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="yes"></iframe>

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `scrolling="no"` or change it to `yes`.

Comment: oveflow-x and overflow-y do not work the same way in all browsers: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html